# How do I create an object upon clicking a button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have an object, "Streak" that I want to be able to create when a button is pressed. What I have are multiple TextInputs and a button. I want the button to be able to get all the inputs and store them in the "Streak" object. How would I go about doing this? Here is the .kv code:

```
<ScreenOne>:
    name: "one"
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
            text: "Back"
            size: 50, 25
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 18
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        rows:6
        Label:
            text: "Action"
            font_size: 18
            size: 600, 50
            size_hint: None, None
        TextInput:
            id: action_entry
            multiline: False
            size: 600, 28
            size_hint: None, None
        Label:
            text: "Streak #"
            size: 600, 50
            size_hint: None, None
        TextInput:
            id: streak_entry
            multiline: False
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 600, 28
        Label:
            size: 600, 50
            size_hint: None, None
            text: "Due every"

        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            rows:2
            Label:
                text: "Day(s)"
                size_hint: None, None
                font_size: 18
            Label:
                text: "Hour(s)"
                size_hint: None, None
                font_size: 18
            Label:
                text: "Minute(s)"
                size_hint: None, None
                font_size: 18
            TextInput:
                id: day_entry
                multiline: False
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 28
            TextInput:
                id: hour_entry
                multiline: False
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 28
            TextInput:
                id: minute_entry
                multiline: False
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 28
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        anchor_y: "bottom"
        Button:
            text: "Add"
            size: 50, 25
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 18
            on_press: Streak.create(instance)
```

Here is the .py code:

```
class Streak():
    def __init__(self, action, action_num, day, hour, minute):
        self.action = action
        self.action_num = action_num
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("StreakStar.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        return presentation

    def create(self, instance):
        streak = Streak(action_entry.text, streak_entry.text, day_entry.text,
                        hour_entry.text, minute_entry.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

When I press the button I get a NameError: name 'Streak' is not definded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root Cause

When `Add` button is pressed, it tried to invoke `Streak.create(instance)` but there is no instantiated object by the name, `Streak` Therefore, it threw the following error:

> NameError: name 'Streak' is not definded

## Solution

### kv file

- Replace `Streak.create(instance)` with `app.create()`

#### Snippets

```
    Button:
        text: "Add"
        size: 50, 25
        size_hint: None, None
        font_size: 18
        on_press: app.create()
```

### py file

- Rewrite method `create()` as follow:

#### Snippets

```
def create(self):
    obj = self.root.get_screen('one')
    self.streak = Streak(obj.ids.action_entry.text, obj.ids.streak_entry.text, obj.ids.day_entry.text, 
                         obj.ids.hour_entry.text, obj.ids.minute_entry.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the ids are already stored in the `ids` library - assuming you want to use this variable as a string you could just concatenate the ids you require.

The reason why you're getting an error is because `streak` isn't previously defined in your function.

```
def create(self):
    streak = ""
    streak = self.ids.action_entry.text +", "+
             self.ids.streak_entry.text +", "+
             self.ids.day_entry.text....
```

Will give you a string of these `ids`